# List initialization still empty

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a function which initializes a list in Python. However, after printing out each element, there is no output. Also, there is no error message either. The goal is to initialize the list with the number zero up to a length. I'm using Online GDB (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter) as my interpreter.  The code is below.

```
def init_list(the_list, length):
    the_list = [0] * length 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_list = [] 
    length = 2 
    init_list(the_list, length)
    [print(str(e)) for e in the_list]
```

Comment: You can't use `print()` like that inside of a list comprehension.

Comment: I also tried print(the_list) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing of the tricks python has for you regarding memory management here. Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) for more details. The right way to do this would be :

```
def init_list(length):
    return [0] * length 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 2 
    the_list = init_list(length)
    print([str(e) for e in the_list])
```

or even

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 2 
    the_list = [0] * length 
    print([str(e) for e in the_list])
```

Comment: This appears to work, but I am not sure what return has to do with it

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is weird to me ... btw here a simplified version of yuor code:

```
def init_list(length):
    the_list = [0] * length
    return the_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = 2
    mylist = init_list(length)
    print([str(e) for e in mylist])
```

Furthermore the print statement within a list comprehension is not a good thing

Comment: This also has the same problem when I ran it

Comment: I just ran te code on my laptop, and it works perfectly printing the list

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to initialize a python list with zeroes. The function you wrote is working but you aren't returning anything. Add a print statement and you will see it is working.

Just return the list after making it. Also, don't use a print statement inside a list comprehension.

```
def init_list(the_list, length):
    the_list = [0] * length 
    print(the_list)
    return the_list
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_list = [] 
    length = 2 
    the_list = init_list([], length)
    print(the_list)
```